# Accessor for field user clashes when porting from django-social-auth to python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I am porting a project from using django-social-auth to python-social-auth. I followed the [instructions](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/porting_from_dsa.html) in the documentation, but when I try to run the project's test (./manage.py test) I get the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default' ...
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
default.usersocialauth: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.social_auth'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
default.usersocialauth: Reverse query name for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.social_auth'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
```

./manage.py syncdb and ./manage migrate work fine, as expected, because (as the documentation states), the models table names in python-social-auth were defined to be compatible with those used on django-social-auth, so data is not needed to be migrated.

Comment: Any chance you have both libs installed and defined on `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I removed django-social-auth from INSTALLED_APPS. Here is a list of my third party installed apps: `INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'registration',
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'haystack',
    'south',
    'djcelery',
    'django_extensions',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
)` Thanks again.

Comment: No. I am sorry for not being clear. I had removed the old lib and only have python-social-auth ('social.apps.django_app.default') installed. I am still experiencing the problem.

Comment: if you are still getting same error, it means that something is still in clashing with new library. Use my answer below to identify what it is and remove it solve the conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into same issue.

Even though django-social-auth library was removed from INSTALLED_APPS, django was still finding the conflict since both django-social-auth and python-social-auth use same foreign keys with same related_name parameter.

To know exactly what model is python-social-auth is clashing with, put a breakpoint in

```
get_validation_errors (validation.py)
```

on line 148 and 150

```
for r in rel_opts.get_all_related_objects():
    if r.field is not f:
        if r.get_accessor_name() == rel_name:
            e.add(opts, "Accessor for field '%s' clashes with related field '%s.%s'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for '%s'." % (f.name, rel_opts.object_name, r.get_accessor_name(), f.name))
        if r.get_accessor_name() == rel_query_name:
            e.add(opts, "Reverse query name for field '%s' clashes with related field '%s.%s'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for '%s'." % (f.name, rel_opts.object_name, r.get_accessor_name(), f.name))
```

looking at 'r' variable will reveal the related object that is clashing.

Removing library django-social-auth completely from the system solved the issue.

Since it was originally installed with easy_install, I used rm -rf  to remove it from site-packages, but also remember to remove the name from easy_install.pth

You can also use pip uninstall

Hope this helps.